# How can I get thumbnails, preview or full DriveItem in response from MS Graph Search REST API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-teams

I'm currently using MS Graph Search REST API preview to request items that are accessible to the current user. The point is requesting files from SharePoint, OneDrive and Teams at once.

In the response I get `_source` field that contains a part of a `driveItem`, but it is not enough to request thumbnails, previewUrls and other data that might be requested separately or by using `$expand` when using `v1.0` API.

It also seems like `_id` and `_source._id` fields are not enough for requesting full info for the `driveItem`.

Here is the request I'm currently using:

POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$batch`

part of `requests` field with requesting documents:

```
{
    id: "Documents",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    },
    url: "/search/query",
    body: {
        requests: [
            {
                entityTypes: [
                    "microsoft.graph.driveItem"
                ],
                query: {
                    query_string: {
                        query: query
                    }
                },
                from: 0,
                size: 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can get thumbnails, previews or a link to the full `driveItem` from the response?

If there is another way of searching through all the accessible documents, such as all accessible OneDrive, SharePoint and MS Teams items in one (or a reasonable amount of) requests, that would really help too.

Comment: By using item id, which you got in response you can fetch thumbnail for the specified drive item. Could you please refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0)? Try if that helps

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, this docs does not allow me to get any item I want. I still need to provide the `driveId`, which is missing. So, it either works if the file belongs to me and can be found as 'me/drive/items/{itemId]` or a direct link to the drive. Trying to get the item by using `drive/items/{itemId}` fails with 'not found' error if I'm trying it in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: You can get drive id by using get [drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). BY using item id and drive id You can fetch the [thumbnail of the item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-thumbnails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)